# Show images of storage forebase on android

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am working with firebase in my android project and what I want is to display different images depending on the selected option in my ListView, but these images are stored in firebase and I still can not find them, I tried different ways but none worked until Moment, if anyone knows how I can do this or where I can find good documentation, it would be very useful thanks.

Comment: Could you add some more details to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of code that worked for me recently. You can find more from this tutorial: https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/gestures-animations-flexible-uis/using-the-camera-and-saving-images-to-firebase

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = decodeFromFirebaseBase64(restaurant.getImageUrl());
mRestaurantImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

public static Bitmap decodeFromFirebaseBase64(String image) throws IOException {
    byte[] decodedByteArray = android.util.Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteArray, 0, decodedByteArray.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did you serve to show your images in your project?